# move files to a date specific folder based on run number and it should be determined based on a counter

Tags: unix

I want to move the `TLR` file as well as all `*.log` and `*.ini` to a date specific folder called in `/app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/mmddyyyy_[Run_Number]`.
 The `[Run_Number]` should be determined based on a counter.
If it is the first run, then it should be 1.
For example: if `/u01/app/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/06202019_1` already exists, then a new directory `/app/hard/ecm2fs/KADE_TLE_Backup/06202019_2` should be created and the files should be moved to there and so on.

Can anyone help me how to do that with unix shell script?

Below is my code which I did

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
date=`date +"%m%d%Y"`;
cd /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/;
if [ ! -d "$date"_1 ];
then
mkdir "$date"_1;
find /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/*.ini -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/"$date"_1/;
find /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/*.log -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/"$date"_1/;
find /app/hard/ec4rd/TLR -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/"$date"_1/;
elif [ -d "$date"_1 ];
then
mkdir "$date"_2;

find /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/*.ini -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup//"$date"_2/;
find /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/*.log -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup//"$date"_2/;
find /app/hard/ec4rd/TLR -type f -mtime -1 | xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/"$date"_2/;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code can easily be generalized by searching for a non-existent target directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
date=`date +"%m%d%Y"`
cd /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup
counter=1
while target="$date"_$counter; [ -d $target ]
do  ((++counter))
done
mkdir $target
find /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/*.ini -type f -mtime -1 |
 xargs -n1 -i mv  {} /app/hard/ec4rd/ec4rd_backup/$target
…
```